# How to mock a 3rd party web service LINQ data provider?

Tags: c#, linq, mocking

What is involved in mocking a LINQ web service data provider, which is made by a 3rd party, and is effectively a black box to me? Here is typical usage of that black box: (modified to protect the innocent, aka an NDA)

```
var conn = new RemoteServer (username,password);
var result = from row in conn.GetSomeData()
    where row.this == "Hello" && row.that != "World"
    select new { row.this, row.that, row.theOther };
```

I so far know `result` is `IEnumerable<T>`.
Another usage example:

```
string something="xxx";
var result = from row in conn.SubscribeAsync()
    where row.this == something
    select new MyObject(something) { row.that, row.theOther };
```

(This will keep pushing data, perhaps a few items each second, and I'll be wanting to mock carefully timed sequences.)

I suppose my real question is, will it be as simple as:

```
 class MockRemoteServer
 {
     IEnumerable GetSomeData()
     {
          return new[]
          {
              new {this="1",that="2",theOther="special"},
              new {this="hello",that="world",theOther="something"}
          }
     }
 }
```

Or do I need to implement a full-on LINQ data provider myself?
If so, any book or article recommendations on this? (My LINQ knowledge is currently based on a cover-to-cover read of Jon Skeet's C# In Depth, and not much else...)

Comment: What you do will based on what you actually want to make sure is working.  I am not 100% sure what you mean by a "full-on" LINQ data provider.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure what I mean by "full-on" either! The c# In Depth book doesn't show how to write a LINQ data provider but mentions in passing that they are non-trivial. One specific concern is if I need to write code to handle the Where clause. (I think not: if my mock version just returns a big block of data, then LINQ To Objects should use its built-in `Where` function to filter it?)

Answer (score 1):

A `List<T>` is generally enough (since it implements IEnumerable). However, if you want to know actual performance of your queries, nothing beats using the actual RemoteServer.